# Solve $\sin x = 1 - x$

Tags: trigonometry

How would you be solve sin x = 1 - x, without drawing the graph and manually measuring the point of intersection?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no closed-form analytical solution for this kind of transcendental equation. You can either solve it graphically (as you said) or numerically. There are various methods for solving it numerically, see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Specific_algorithms) for an overview.

If you're not looking for a particularly efficient solution, the simplest thing to do in this case might be to write the equation as

$$x=1-\sin x$$

and iterate the map

$$x_{n+1}=1-\sin x_n$$

until you achieve satisfactory convergence. This is very inefficient, though; it only makes sense if you do it on a computer and don't mind if it takes a lot of operations; you'll need a lot of patience to get anywhere with it with a calculator. :-)

A far more efficient method that yields $x$ to double-precision machine accuracy within a couple of iterations would be [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method):

$$f(x) = x + \sin x - 1 \stackrel{!}{=} 0\;,$$

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}=x_n - \frac{x+\sin x - 1}{1 + \cos x}\;.$$

Comment: Is there any problem with the following approach? $\sin (\pi/2-x)=1-(\pi/2-x) \rightarrow \cos(x)=1-(\pi/2-x)$. Then use the identity $sin^2 x+cos^2 x=1$ to find x

Comment: If the figure of merit is operator time instead of computer time, a spreadsheet can make the programming very easy.  Just put a starting value (0.5 is a good one, as others have said) in A1, =1-sin(x) in B1, =B1 in A2, and copy down until you see convergence.

Comment: @user11869: I don't understand -- how would you then use that identity to find $x$?

Comment: $(1-x)^2+[1-(\pi/2-x)]^2=1$ and solve this equation

Comment: @user11869: I see. You're assuming that the given equation holds both for $x$ and for $\pi/2-x$. But there's no reason why it should hold for $\pi/2-x$.

Comment: @joriki: how can one see that there is no closed form solution? (looking at the date of the answer, I'm very late though...;))

Comment: @Nils: I'm not aware of any formal method of proving that. There may be one, but I was merely expressing knowledge from experience: I'd be very surprised if there were a closed-form solution because I've never seen any for equations like this, and I'm pretty sure I would have come across them if they were known.

Comment: @joriki: ah, too bad. I've never seen a formal argument in favor of the kind of statement "xy cannot be expressed by using certain standard-functions", so I was hoping for one. Anyway, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @Nils: You may be interested in this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm

Comment: @joriki: interesting, thanks!

Comment: @Nils: Also this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral

Answer (score 7):

Below is a calculus-type approach. Remark that to first order $\sin x \simeq x,$ so your result will be somewhere around $x = \frac{1}{2}.$ That suggests a Taylor expansion of sine around $\frac{\pi}{6} \simeq \frac{1}{2}.$ You can introduce $\epsilon = x - \frac{\pi}{6},$ such that $$\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\epsilon - \frac{1}{4}\epsilon^2 + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^3).$$
Identifying $1 - x = 1 - (\frac{\pi}{6} + \epsilon),$ you can equate both sides of your equation and solve a linear, quadratic, ..., polynomial equation in $\epsilon$, which will however involve knowing a reasonable approximation to $\pi$ and/or $\frac{\pi}{6}.$

Answer (score 6):

For such cases, I would use [Wims Function Calculator](http://wims.unice.fr/wims/en_tool~analysis~function.en.html). Type the function $f(x)=\sin(x)-(1-x)$, and check the last box to find the root of the equation $\sin(x)-(1-x) = 0$. You can obtain the value of the root even up to $200$ digits. In your example, the root is approximately $0.51097342938856910952001397114508063204535889262375023988987953800752819385525987164073419474333797073844705378201625612601584766524335342369803019732463083576632594596747582089441042803074463769962092$.

Answer (score 4):

As joriki mentions, simple-minded fixed-point iteration works if you're not too concerned about efficiency in obtaining the numerical solution (One usually has to be very lucky to obtain a closed form solution for a transcendental equation; this is not one of those lucky situations.). I'll only note that making use of the fact that $\sin\;x\approx x$, you can then say that there is a solution very near $x=.5$. Feed that to a fixed-point iteration, Newton, or Halley, and you can then obtain a good numerical approximation (which Shai has already given for you).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "solving". If you want to show that a solution exists, use the intermediate value theorem. Expressing the solution by "elementary functions" (also called an analytical solution or closed-form solution, but note that these terms don't have universal definitions) is not possible. If you want a numerical solution, then use Newton's method.

Comment: Using Newton-Raphson method

$f(x) := sin(x) + x - 1$, $ f'(x) = cos(x) + 1$,

$x = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$


$x = x - \frac{sin(x) + x - 1}{cos(x) + 1}$,

Use an initial estimate between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ i.e. $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and iterate?

Answer (score 1):

As @Gerben answered, building the Taylor series around $x=\frac \pi 6$ gives
$$y=x+\sin(x)-1=\frac{\pi -3}{6} +\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2} x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)}{2 n!} \left(x-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)^n$$
Truncated to $O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)^6\right)$ for example and using series reversion, then
$$x=\frac{\pi }{6}+t+\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)
   t^2+\left(3-\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}}\right) t^3+\left(\frac{67}{6}-\frac{77}{4
   \sqrt{3}}\right) t^4+\left(\frac{232}{5}-\frac{803}{10 \sqrt{3}}\right)
   t^5+O\left(t^{6}\right)$$ where $t=\frac{y+\frac{3-\pi }{6}}{1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$.

Making $y=0$ that is to say $t=-\frac{\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right) (\pi -3)}{3} $, this gives
$x=0.51097342938847$ while the exact solution is
$x=0.51097342938857$.