# Square inscribed in a circle and an angle

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Consider this badly drawn picture and the circle in the picture. Suppose that the circle has unit length, so that the area is $\pi$. Suppose that We know that the area enclosed by $ABCD$ is exactly $\pi/12$. Can one then find the angle $CAB$?If so, how? I tried analytic methods, but to no real help.

[image: Square in a circle]

Comment: Hmm, a numerial approximation with Mathematica: 0.2681334894944452

Comment: Please crop the image link so that it doesn't have a full page of white space below the picture itself.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\theta$ be the angle $CAB$ in radians. Then the area ABCD is equal to $\frac{\theta+\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{2}=\frac{\pi}{12}$.
Rearranging that and using $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$, we get that $\theta$ satisfies $2\theta+\sin(2\theta)=\frac{\pi}{3}$.

I'm not sure if there exists an analytical solution to this: 
[Solve $\sin x = 1 - x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26358/solve-sin-x-1-x)

However, Mathematica gives $0.2681334894944452$ as a numerical approximation.

Comment: Where does the area formula come from?

Comment: @RainiervanEs $\frac{\theta}{2}$ for the area $ABC$ and $\frac{\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{2}$ for $ACD$.